# In memory alternative to datasets

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dataset, nosql, data-processing

I am moving a complex process out of SQL to a .NET application. I'm kind of taking a brute force approach by pulling down only the data that is needed from SQL, then storing in datatables. Using a pipeline pattern with stepping, I broke out the processes that can be done in parallel (not dependent upon the other processes, nor working on the same data bits).

Everything is going fine, but I want to know if there is an in-memory sql solution that would perform better than the DataSet/DataTable structures. We're talking about 50k rows at a time with up to 1m supporting data rows (read 5b rows). Row size for 1 row (with all supporting data rows) is probably around 1K avg (due to large strings).

My question is specifically on the performance of DataSets, memory overhead and persistence. I will need to serialize the data at each stage to disk for recovery purposes.

Would it be better to just map the rows to a strongly typed model instead? I don't need any relationships or other benefits of datasets; I replaced most of the search functionality with my own using parallel processing.

Data only uses primitive types, no blobs, streams, geography etc.

Comment: As far as turning it into a strongly typed model, I'd say it depends on the data you're representing.  Also, what are you attempting to do with/to the data once in memory?  Knowing this might help myself and others to determine the best approach/best advice for the situation.

Comment: About 100 different processes need to happen. Checking records for duplicates, data calculations and aggregations, updates, deletes, etc. The resulting final dataset gets pushed back to SQL. Some processes require join and group like functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For local SQL operations, take a look at SQLite. I don't recall offhand if it can run exclusively in memory, but with disk caching and transaction journalling turned off it would probably be pretty close.

Steve Shaunessey developed a fast in-memory SQL engine at Borland many years ago. I don't know if it was ever productized. Take a look around the Embarcadero.com web site to see if any remnants of his work have survived.

I noticed aidaim.com advertises an in-memory SQL engine. No experience with it, just FYI.

Also consider LINQ for in-memory query operations. If you pay attention to what you're doing, LINQ's query composition and deferred execution work well with large data, IMO. And, no SQL parser required.

Comment: +1 - and yes, it can run completely in memory.  See http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Aha, the little grey cells were firing on all cylinders for a change.  I haven't worked with SQLite since using it to build Google Gears, but had a vague recollection that in-memory was an option. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Thanks @dthorpe, I downloaded SQLite earlier before making this post but haven't gotten to play with it yet.

Comment: That was BlackFishSQL (nah, NDataStore, nah JDataStore). It was very promising, and could have ruled the .NET Mobile world. But it has not been marketed well and been dropped from the Delphi/C++Builder/RADStudio SKUs since XE http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/blackfish_sql_replacement.html though still on the Embarcadero site, I guess it is dead http://www.embarcadero.com/products/blackfish-sql